# Clearing File Upload

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer

I have jQuery function to validate the file extension of the uploaded file. If the the file does not belong to a desired file extensions then a validation message will be shown and I will clear the value of `File Upload` via jQuery as

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload').val("")
```

It is working fine in modern browsers but not in IE 8. I also tried

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload').value = ''
```

but not working also. my full code is

```
if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp']) == -1) {
    alert('Image must be .jpg/.jpeg/.gif/.bmp/.png only.');
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload').val("");
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload').value = '';
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has some **[security restriction(read-only)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx)** over `<input type="file">`

So, a workaround would be **[clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** and replace the current `<input>`:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf('MSIE') >= 0){
    $("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
} else {
    $("input[type='file']").val('');
}
```

Also, form `$('#form')[0].reset();` can be an option in case it is the only field in the form.

Comment: When I try to Implement the above code I am getting **"'$.browser.msie' is null or not an object"** error

Comment: what is the jquery version you are using? `$.browser.msie`  is deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks @shaunakde The `.browser` call has been removed in jquery 1.9 so I referenced [jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) on this Link in my page